# Converting static variable to memory

Tags: storage, memory

I have the following code snippet in my contract, trying to call flashLoan from Aave.

```
address private constant LINK = 0x...;

   function myFlashLoanCall(uint256 _amount, bytes memory _params) public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);
        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        uint256[] memory amount = [_amount];
        uint256[] memory mode;

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            [LINK],
            amount,
            mode,
            onBehalfOf,
            _params,
            0
        );
    }
```

When I try to compile I get the following two errors:

```
TypeError: Type uint256[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory.
        uint256[] memory amount = [_amount];
        ^---------------------------------^
```

and

```
 TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address[1] memory to address[] memory requested.
            [LINK],
            ^----^
```

What am I doing wrong for each error. How should my code be structured instead?

Comment: why are you declaring array of amounts ? are you going to call multiple flashloans? just single uint256 amount variable is enough. remove this line `uint256[] memory amount` and pass amount directly to `flashLoan()` , add `memory` keyword to the parameter `amount` in function's signature. The amount is what you want to borrow

Comment: The flashloan from aave takes arrays as params. If I try what you suggest I get: ```TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address[] memory requested.
            LINK,
```